# Retrieve and modify the value of an interface element in another Mac OS application

Tags: macos, cocoa

On Mac OS, I've seen a few application that manage to control the user interface elements of other applications in order to provide a new way to control them (via a track pad, for example).

Can anyone please tell me how that's done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some obvious (and *non-hackish*) ways to achieve that would include

- [Accessibility](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000118-SW1), or
- [Apple Script](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html)